# Execute in future - time doubles somehow

Tags: java, time

I am very sorry to ask this question but something is going wrong with my code. Currently I am playing around with Command Patterns and I want a command class to execute code in the future - lets say 2 seconds in the future. The problem somehow is that the command gets executed in 5 seconds, not in 2??? Each call decreases a time variable until the variable is <= 0:

```
// 2 seconds in nanoseconds
private long timeLeft = 2000000000;

public boolean execute(final long delta) {
    this.timeLeft -= delta;
    if (this.timeLeft <= 0) {
        // execute
        this.timeLeft = 2000000000l;
    return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

With `lastExecution = System.nanoTime();` and then for each command `delta = System.nanoTime() - lastExecution;`

Full src on github: https://github.com/Sheldor5/JavaGPP

Answer (score 0):

Instead of decrementing a countdown timer value by inaccurate deltas, calculate the target time and check for it, and use milli-time, not nano-time, to prevent sign issues.

```
long targetMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000; // 2 sec
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < targetMillis) {
    // do something while we wait
}
// 2 secs elapsed, may be a bit more
```

Comment: This is the easier way but I want to know what is wrong with my code too to learn from my mistakes ;) any ideas? but thankt you ^^